# What are best practices for jenkins security?

Tags: jenkins

What are the best practices for a jenkins installation like the one below?
I do have a quite small dedicated server with 16 gb of ram and 2tb of diskspace with enabled hardware virtualization, and one use of it would be to host my own projects (opensource), and there are applications set up such as git repository manager and stuff.
I would like to set up jenkins there for automatic building, but I want to make it secure.
This installation is small enough to require only a master node, but I am planning to disable building on master completely, and to run a virtual machine as an agent, for the reason that it would be isolated as much as possible on the same physical server, so that a job would be unable to destroy jenkins master data.
Should I go for master only anyway? or, if using a virtual machine agent, should I have only one executor there or multiple ones? I probably cannot isolate multiple parallel jobs running on one agent without using one agent per job, but maybe I am overthinking all this. Using one agent per job, at least in case of virtual machines, would exhaust server resources very quickly, or alternatively, money.

Comment: Depends on too many factors.. adding build agents is never wrong. The level of separation needed depends on your environment.

Comment: separation is not strictly needed as I rather do not expect to be giving access to others to build server job configuration or stuff, but I wanted to secure it just in case, also making it well would probably make it easier to have a clean environment for every build, and allow build to do many weird things like installing packages to the vm temporarily, knowing that changes can be reverted then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins own database of users, which I have used in commercial settings and it has worked perfectly well. If you have Active Directory you can also integrate with this if you want to go to extra effort so people only have to remember one login.

Once users are logged in you should provide authorisation via the [Role-Strategy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) plugin